# Integrating results to ALM using pywinauto

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, pywinauto, alm

I am automating windows based application using pywinauto. How to integrate test results to ALM using pywinauto and how to run scripts through ALM using pywinauto.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ALM, so integrating test results looks like a job for pytest or other testing/reporting tool (and this is completely separate question). Running scripts from ALM looks like remote execution. Please read [Remote Execution Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html) for pywinauto.

P.S. StackOverflow (further SO) community may encourage you to improve questions quality. So please add as more details as possible into your questions. So the ALM result reporting question should be asked separately because it's easier to decide which issue is resolved and which is still not. It's good practice to accept correct answers (gray check box at the left side under voting buttons should work for an author of question).

P.P.S. Also recommendation questions are not welcome on SO. Maybe it's better to ask ALM maintainers directly about reporting capabilities for Python tests. SO question should figure out some detailed problem and your efforts should be visible. Ideally it's some piece of code with detailed error message and maybe logs/printouts/screenshots.